# Como cambiar guardar un archivo CSV por dia en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Estoy programando un ejecutable en Python que pueda tomar datos de una web diariamente a determinada hora y guardar dicha info en un CSV diferente cada día, con nombre del csv de la fecha + nombre de página web.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Ya tengo el ejecutable programado en mac, pero **debe cambiar el nombre del archivo según un día distinto.**

Actualmente tengo esto:

```
import csv

file = open("aquifecha + nombre pagina web.csv", "w", newline='')
spamreader = csv.writer(file)
spamreader.writerow(final_f)
file.close()
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Con este comando: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm puedes obtener la fecha y hora actual. No se como sea en Mac, pero en Windows hay algo llamado "programador de tareas", que entre otras funciones permite ejecutar un programa diariamente cada cierta hora. Quiza en Mac haya algo similar o algun programa de un tercero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la librería `datetime` y en en ella el módulo `date` tiene la función `today()` que nos devuelve el día en el que nos encontramos. Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
import datetime
import csv

file = open(datetime.date.today().strftime("%d_%m_%y")
            + "nombre pagina web.csv", "w", newline='')

spamreader = csv.writer(file)
spamreader.writerow(final_f)
file.close()
```

Hacemos un `print()` de la variable `file`:

```
print(file)
```

**Salida** `02_02_21_nombre pagina web.csv`

**Explicación**

1. Llamamos a la función `today()` la fecha en formate `date`
2. Invocamos el método `strftime` (string format time) para pasar nuestra fecha de formato `date` a `str`

Como puedes ver el método `strftime` tiene una notación propia, indicando día, mes y año `%d` `%m` `%y`. Puedes ver más sobre esta notación en la [documentación oficial de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: Sugeriría que el formato de la fecha sea `%y_%m_%d`, así te saldrán siempre en orden cronológico.

Comment: Yo creo que es mejor usar `time.strftime`, que si se le pasa como unico argumento el formato de la fecha (ej: "%d-%m-%Y") obtiene la fecha actual en forma de cadena.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, en especial a ALberto. Me ha sido de mucha ayuda y pude resolver mi problema.